# How to show the source code in Sentry's stack trace?

Tags: javascript, sentry

I am using Sentry for collecting JavaScript errors. Also, I do not use build tools like Webpack or Vite to transpile JavaScript.　Therefore, I am not outputting source maps.
In this case, is there a way to show JavaScript source code in Sentry's stack trace?

Here's an example.

In this case, I'd like to show the source code of `somethingWrong.js` in the Sentry's stack trace.

```js
// somethingWrong.js

function somethingWrong() {
  throw new Error("somethingWrong");
}

somethingWrong();
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<script src="path/to/somethingWrong.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem has been solved.

See: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/discussions/10631#discussioncomment-8456005